# Mails don't send after upgrade from v1.9.1.0 to v1.9.2.0

Tags: email, header

after Magento upgrade from  v1.9.1.0 to v1.9.2.0 mails stopped sending. In system.log I see an error HRADERS ALREDY SENT. However, this message appear when I press Add to cart button, but users' checkout process goes smoothly. Moreover, I see successful orders in the dashboard where it is said that customer is notified and status order - pending. Thus, I am not sure whether this issue causes problem with email.

In addition, I have a list of files in system.log that are loaded and probably have white space or BOM and I checked them but found nothing. The list contains 334 files, so it is possible that I miss something. Is there a way to find a file that causes Headers error ?

Also, I checked if I can send email just using mail() from "simple" php - it works.

How to start solving problem with emails. I read that I should select crone.php in cPanel, and I did it. How to know whether emails are not being formed or could not be sent?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should check is `exception.log` to see if there is anything that can help there.

In the Magento 1.9.2 upgrade they have added a mail queue system for some of the emails that get sent. The account success email is [sent immediately](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php#L667):

```
$mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig($sender, $storeId));
$mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
$mailer->setTemplateId(Mage::getStoreConfig($template, $storeId));
$mailer->setTemplateParams($templateParams);
$mailer->send();
```

However emails such as the [order invoice order](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php#L1350) is added to the mail queue and is sent on cron:

```
$emailQueue = Mage::getModel('core/email_queue');
$emailQueue->setEntityId($this->getId())
            ->setEntityType(self::ENTITY)
            ->setEventType(self::EMAIL_EVENT_NAME_NEW_ORDER)
            ->setIsForceCheck(!$forceMode);
$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

You should should have your cron setup to run around every 5 minutes.
See [magento cron](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#system-operations/cron.html?Highlight=cron) your should also look at installing [AOE_Scheduler](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html) to help manage your cron tasks

Comment: exception.log is not created. However, I have just found that emails were created in database. By the way, cron is configured. I will dig towards the cron.

Comment: Well, I found that I should add a string to cron.php $isShellDisabled = true;. Now my cron.php is called from cPanel.

Comment: Did this get your emails working?

Comment: Yes, I did and now mails are sent. However, it still needs tuning, because my cPanel sent me a notification once with an error: Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/ProductAlert/Model/Observer.php on line 135. But, I will observe it.